# Adobe XD component is not changing state in preview

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd

I have created a prototype in XD and set up a navigation bar. My navigation bar has different states when you press a button for a new screen. The problem I am having is that when I enter preview, the states for my nav bar do not change to reflect the current app page.\Is there a way to fix this?

Home

[image: 1]

Video

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out just in case someone comes across this same issue. You have to go to each screen and change the state of the component on that specific screen.